# List Channel Messages using Application Permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an Application which accesses channel messages in Microsoft Teams. We have been using the "Group.Read.All" permission for the last few months to access these messages, but just today we have started getting 403 for these requests? Has something changed?

I appreciate the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) flag this as "Not supported" but it has been working with no issue until today.

We are trying to use the following request;

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages
```

However we are now getting a 403 Forbidden response;

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "xxx",
            "date": "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've run into the same exact issue. I've attempted to add more permissions but still receive the "UnknownError." I did notice that the URL you posted is incorrect as it shows `/beta/teams/teams` when the endpoint is just `/beta/teams/`

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the url, copy and pasted wrong. Just checked again this morning and still have the same issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though Microsoft has locked down these particular permissions and you'll need to request access to them for your particular app. See their documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis